# Android Emojicon Library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, emoji

I am new to android development and am trying to use this https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon/ library. I don't understand the instructions on how to use the library. I have never used any other library, so can someone please post a step by step method to use this library for my android project in Android Studio.

EDIT: What I meant by use was how to include it into my project, turns out it was as simple as just adding a line in the gradle file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you add the the following to your `app/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
   //Add this line:
   compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.0'
}
```

Once you re-sync your project, you can then use the library as per the [examples](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon/tree/master/example) (Layout example [here](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon#example))

Comment: I was being stupid and following the steps needed to follow for eclipse. I figured it out. Anyways Thanks.